# How to stop page from scrolling in off-canvas menu?

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Utility */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1160px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.dark {
  background: #000;
}

.active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

/* Home */
.showcase {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;

  background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  animation: slide 18s infinite;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;

  width: 100%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  }

  20% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg2.jpg);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg3.jpg);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg4.jpg);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg5.jpg);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  }
}

/* Personal */
.pimg1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("../img/homebg/bg1.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
}

.pimg2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("../img/homebg/bg2.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
}

.ptext1 {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Hamburger menu */

.menu-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  top: 55px;
  right: 280px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  top: 55px;
  right: 270px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Hamburger Icon */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

/* Show Menu */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
  /* transform: scale(1); */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0.1s;
}

/* Menu overlay */
.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* transform: scale(0); */
  transform: translateY(20%);
  /* transition: all 0.1s ease; */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Hamburger centered */
.h-center {
  position: absolute;
  right: 48% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" />

    <title>Мышонок</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background: #000">
    <!-- Hamburger -->

    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler h-center" />
      <div class="hamburger h-center"><div></div></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="personal.html" class="active">Personal</a></li>
              <li><a href="men.html">Men</a></li>
              <li><a href="women.html">Women</a></li>
              <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pimg1"></div>
    <div class="pimg2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

1) I have a page with content.
2) I have a hamburger menu which when clicked brings the off-canvas menu

I need:

To not be able to scroll my page with content when I am in the off-canvas menu. How to achieve that?

P.S. I can add the code if that is needed. But perhaps it is simple question for someone. Tell me if you need the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set body overflow to hidden using javascript or jquery or add a class

CSS:

```
.scroll-off{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

script:

```
$(body).addClass('scroll-off');
```

or

```
$(body).css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

for more information, you can read more about jquery in [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Example:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click Me</button>

<div style="width: 300px; height: 1000px; background-color: red;margin: 0px auto;"></div>

</body>
<script>
var index = 0;
$('button').click(function () {
 if(index == 0){
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  index = 1;
    }else if(index == 1){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  index = 0;
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

this is your file whit script code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Utility */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1160px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.dark {
  background: #000;
}

.active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

/* Home */
.showcase {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;

  background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  animation: slide 18s infinite;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;

  width: 100%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  }

  20% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg2.jpg);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg3.jpg);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg4.jpg);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg5.jpg);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(../img/homebg/bg1.jpg);
  }
}

/* Personal */
.pimg1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("../img/homebg/bg1.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
}

.pimg2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("../img/homebg/bg2.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
}

.ptext1 {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Hamburger menu */

.menu-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  top: 55px;
  right: 280px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  top: 55px;
  right: 270px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Hamburger Icon */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

/* Show Menu */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
  /* transform: scale(1); */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0.1s;
}

/* Menu overlay */
.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* transform: scale(0); */
  transform: translateY(20%);
  /* transition: all 0.1s ease; */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Hamburger centered */
.h-center {
  position: absolute;
  right: 48% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Мышонок</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background: #000">
    <!-- Hamburger -->

    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler h-center" />
      <div class="hamburger h-center"><div></div></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="personal.html" class="active">Personal</a></li>
              <li><a href="men.html">Men</a></li>
              <li><a href="women.html">Women</a></li>
              <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pimg1"></div>
    <div class="pimg2"></div>
 
 
<script>
var index = 0;
$('.toggler').click(function () {
 if(index == 0){
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  index = 1;
    }else if(index == 1){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  index = 0;
    }
});
</script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know how to write JavaScript. Can I target body and add propety with CSS?

For example, I was trying to achieve this like this:

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

but it didn't work

Comment: no, you must use javascript or jquery to do that.
I will edit my answer for you if you can include your code I can help you better

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thank you very much. I'm learning JavaScript, so if it's possible for you to write me the same solution with pure  JavaScript with no jQuery, I could figure out how you did that. If you can, It would be very helpful. Thank you, anyway!

Comment: for pure javascript, you can use document.getElementByName or ById or ByClassName for more information please check w3schools.com